# Why does ECDSA produce different signatures for the same data, whereas RSA doesn't?

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa, signing, ecdsa

Consider the following code using RSA...

**Example:**

```cs
byte[] raw = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Hello, World!");
RSA key = RSA.Create();

for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
{
    byte[] signed = key.SignData(raw, HashAlgorithmType.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
    string hashed = signed.ToSha256String();
    Console.WriteLine(hashed);
}
```

**Output:**

> 043a718774c572bd8a25adbeb1bfcd5c0256ae11cecf9f9c3f925d0e52beaf89
> 043a718774c572bd8a25adbeb1bfcd5c0256ae11cecf9f9c3f925d0e52beaf89
> 043a718774c572bd8a25adbeb1bfcd5c0256ae11cecf9f9c3f925d0e52beaf89
> 043a718774c572bd8a25adbeb1bfcd5c0256ae11cecf9f9c3f925d0e52beaf89
> 043a718774c572bd8a25adbeb1bfcd5c0256ae11cecf9f9c3f925d0e52beaf89

Now consider the same code, except using ECDSA...

**Example:**

```cs
byte[] raw = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Hello, World!");
ECDsa key = ECDsa.Create();

for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
{
    byte[] signed = key.SignData(raw, HashAlgorithmType.SHA256);
    string hashed = signed.ToSha256String();
    Console.WriteLine(hashed);
}
```

**Output:**

> 043a718774c572bd8a25adbeb1bfcd5c0256ae11cecf9f9c3f925d0e52beaf89
> a31fe9656fc8d3a459e623dc8204e6d0268f8df56d734dac3ca3262edb5db883
> a871c47a7f48a12b38a994e48a9659fab5d6376f3dbce37559bcb617efe8662d
> d7ef0a04f3c8055644677299a9414a75adcb15916eb48417416c9317ace2ff4f
> 779f5dd63960abda52a7da70464b92eedd47f84a8dffda2d672e6a99de1bab95

RSA's signature output I expected; ECDSA's, I didnt. Why does ECDSA produce different signatures for the same data?

Comment: RSA with PKCs#1 v1.5 padding is deterministic, i.e. generates the same signature with the same input parameters. This is not the case if you use PSS as padding. ECDSA is generally not deterministic, i.e. generates different signatures for the same input parameters. However, there is also a deterministic variant for ECDSA, which is not supported in .NET out of the box, but by C#/BouncyCastle, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68899637/9014097).

Comment: Building on @Topaco's points, if you want deterministic signature over elliptic curves use EdDSA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The signature of ECDSA consists of a combination of `R` and `S`, where `R` is a value that is dependent of random parameter `k` which is in turn [input into the ECDSA algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm). `S` in turn depends on that value. If `R` would be a static value then it would [allow an attacker to calculate the private key (!)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm#Security).

The fact that signature generation using PKCS#1 v1.5 padding is deterministic makes it the odd one out. Actually, RSA with PSS padding is randomized using an explicit salt, so the deterministic behavior is not tied to RSA in any way; you could even say that it is an unwanted property as it does expose information about the message / data that has been signed, potentially to other parties than the verifier.

It is however possible to calculate `k` [using a deterministic scheme based on the message itself and the private key](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6979.html) if you must. This may have *some* advantages in particular protocols; for instance it means that no random number generator needs to be present. Generally it is recommended to the non-deterministic / randomized version of ECDSA.

In the end, the proof is in the pudding: if verification with the public key succeeds then your signature generation procedure was according to specification. For the scheme to be secure the public key must of course be validated and trusted, among other requirements.

Answer (score 7):

[Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) (ECDSA), that is an adaptation of the classical DSA algorithm, relies on a cryptographically secure [random number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation). For example: ECDSA signing algorithm calculates a message's hash, then generates a random integer `k` and calculates the signature (a pair of integers {`R`, `S`} ). `R` is calculated from `k`, and `S` is calculated using the message hash + the private key + the random number `k`. So, the signature is ***non-deterministic*** due to a randomness.

You can experiment with an Elliptic Curve [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ialhd71we3?lang=en).