# OpenSSL ECDSA ASN.1 Signature vs WebCrypto ECDSA

Tags: javascript, php, asn.1, ecdsa, webcrypto

Let's use a test key (don't use it, it's just a test, I don't use it either):

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQgkeS6LTDov1L2oShp6PgM2STESyMD1YTQkxUtxSJc1PahRANCAAR+uKNDd0l2odP4excxvTBY5bQxQBufCYb2TkVgp1NBefyO603LHzOelGVnnIFfamtJvv55AwVxt0nUlS0z450U
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I want to sign in Javascript and verify in PHP but I don't get the same result so I tried to get at first same result for signing. Here is my code:

PHP:

```
$challenge=file_get_contents("/tmp/challenge-XIABFf");
$key=openssl_pkey_get_private(file_get_contents("/tmp/private-key"));
$response="";
openssl_sign($challenge,$response, $key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA384);
var_dump(base64_encode($response));
```

I get : `MEYCIQCQt9+reL0WRzi26ft8CEUMRDhnd4vh50F3sYL9BA2x0QIhAJCD7bakD6jXIfYTNpEoGPTR9guusC7CFxbbFcKPvroq` which is 96 characters.

Now in JS :

```
function arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
        var binary = '';
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        for (var i = 0; i < bytes.byteLength; i++) {
            binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
        }
        return btoa(binary);
    }
function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    var binary_string = atob(base64);
    var len = binary_string.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes.buffer;
}

key=await window.crypto.subtle.importKey("pkcs8",base64ToArrayBuffer("MIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQgkeS6LTDov1L2oShp6PgM2STESyMD1YTQkxUtxSJc1PahRANCAAR+uKNDd0l2odP4excxvTBY5bQxQBufCYb2TkVgp1NBefyO603LHzOelGVnnIFfamtJvv55AwVxt0nUlS0z450U"), {name: "ECDSA", namedCurve: "P-256"},true,["sign"]);
message=await window.crypto.subtle.sign({"name": "ECDSA", "hash": "SHA-384"},key,base64ToArrayBuffer("4BRYPzkacla7x5uR0bXtkQXC18odd9yCfcefjIrh")); console.log(arrayBufferToBase64(message));
```

The 4BRY... is the base64 of the challenge. And the result is : `ZDDWSkpkwS8N8LYhHib/Qeb+P8DMRtKIT925AhO8m6bD/K5wAYEYa3Fq89Ik8z6t62a0dtuN8kydxNWttgFcdA==` (88 characters) which is not the same as PHP, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some deep and help from @Dhaval-purohit, I identified why there is a 8 characters difference between my signature.

- First of all, ECDSA signatures [are not deterministic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68959590/why-does-ecdsa-produce-different-signatures-for-the-same-data-whereas-rsa-doesn), they are different each time. So it is pointless to try to get the same output in different languages.
- After deep into [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1797) and [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/164906), WebCrypto signature is in r|s format and OpenSSL is waiting for a ASN.1 format, which have more bytes. This is why OpenSSL was not recognizing the signature of JS. ASN.1 format is the format used in the [blockchain of Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2376/ecdsa-r-s-encoding-as-a-signature).
- Then, I needed to do the conversion but this is quite complicated and noone has shared some code to do it so I searched.

I found this library ([called jsrsassign](https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign)) on Github and they do [import functions](https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign/wiki/Tutorial-for-interoperability-with-OpenSSL-in-ECDSA-signing-and-verification) to do the trick such as :

- asn1SigToConcatSig - convert from a hexadecimal ASN.1 EC signature to a hexadecimal concatenated EC signature
- concatSigToASN1Sig - convert from a hexadecimal concatenated EC signature to a hexadecimal ASN.1 EC signature

They need the hexadecimal form so using this function, you can sign and get a result that OpenSSL can match :

```
/* Stackoverflow DorianCoding */
async function signchallenge(key, challenge) {
            var response = await window.crypto.subtle.sign({
                name: "ECDSA",
                hash: "SHA-384"
            }, key, base64ToArrayBuffer(challenge));
            if (!response) return Promise.reject();
            return arrayBufferToBase64(hextoArrayBuffer(KJUR.crypto.ECDSA.concatSigToASN1Sig(ArrayBuffertohex(response))));
        }
```

You need to implement arraybuffer <=> base64 and hex <=> base64 functions (there is example in my question).

Then a signature like :
3d282410b1f47bfb0a4aae0caf7bef2a59d62b4ecd41037ff913cd71e922a26843c390e1a042cf6199421e55f12b4983845f5c503fcac1b70e3f8e13ec39a8bb

turns into :

3045022100e28ba263bfa655a5bbe2b84d6ef2cdcb821d941f60e375c17b016030eb10e97e0220219927e83f702626ef00dcd0714c232cb5299730b29082e3ec72e94c0b776da2

and as first byte are often the same (3045, ASN.1 format should start by MEU/QCI... in base64) :

```
MEQCID0oJBCx9Hv7CkquDK977ypZ1itOzUEDf/kTzXHpIqJoAiBDw5DhoELPYZlCHlXxK0mDhF9cUD/KwbcOP44T7Dmouw==
```

And now OpenSSL is happy.