# How to apply P1363 format on deterministic ECDSA - Bouncy Castle?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, bouncycastle, ecdsa

I don't find any reference for deterministic with **P1363** format. the `r` and `s` always different in deterministic mode.

**Non-Deterministic** with P1363 -> `WithPlain-ECDSA`  OK

```
        ISigner sign = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA256WithPlain-ECDSA");            
        sign.Init(true, privateKey);
        sign.BlockUpdate(message, 0, message.Length);
        byte[] signedBytes = sign.GenerateSignature();   // Signature can divded by 2. OK
```

**Deterministic way**: (How to apply `WithPlain-ECDSA`?)

```
        var signer = new ECDsaSigner(new HMacDsaKCalculator(new Sha256Digest()));
        signer.Init(true, privateKey);
        var toto = signer.GenerateSignature(message);
        var r = toto[0].ToByteArray();   // sometimes r are equqal s
        var s = toto[1].ToByteArray();   // sometimes s larger than s byte one.
```

I can't return `r.Concat(s).ToArray()`. There's no way to convert `r` and `s` to `byte[]` untill it converted to P1363? which doesn't exist in deterministic version above...

1. How to concatenate `r` and `s` in byte[] in P1363 format?
2. How to make sure I can convert it back through take half of array for `r` and other half for `s`.
3. Sometimes `r` equal `s`, or `s` larger than `r`, How to make sure exactly both are equal when generated?

I don't find any reference for P1363. But I found only [ASN1 DER format](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Signers/ECDsaSigner/GenerateSignature/php-ecdsasigner-generatesignature-method-examples.html#0xae3bf410e95a166820cc72a70b2e6aa865e2c960c726996df86155f10ee23f23-71,,87,):

```
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        using (Asn1OutputStream asn1stream = new Asn1OutputStream(ms))
        {
            DerSequenceGenerator seq = new DerSequenceGenerator(asn1stream);
            seq.AddObject(new DerInteger(s));
            seq.AddObject(new DerInteger(s));
            seq.Close();
            var arrr =  ms.ToArray();
        }
```

Am also tried this [trick](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Signers/ECDsaSigner/GenerateSignature/php-ecdsasigner-generatesignature-method-examples.html#0xb7e272280cd07f8b0cf8cb88a6cb058a6fe8ad5042df30345acb1e875be18862-336,,370,)
But I looped 1000 and check if arrays of `r.Length` == `s.Length`, No equality in all loop.. As he use `BigInteger.ToByteArrayUnsigned()`.

Not sure exactly 100% if above guy's trick work, But the guy try to generate it in fixed way:

```
   Array.Copy(sig1, 0, sig, 0 + (32 - sig1.Length), sig1.Length);
    Array.Copy(sig2, 0, sig, 32 + (32 - sig2.Length), sig2.Length);
```

**Short Answer:**

According to @Topaco answer, its fast manual approach. Many thanks to him. There's also two classes we can use after investigation `StandardDsaEncoding` and `PlainDsaEncoding` classes

1. `StandardDsaEncoding` used to encode/decode ASN1.Der format.
2. `PlainDsaEncoding` used to encode/decode P1363 format.

`PlainDsaEncoding.Instance.Encode()` // This convert to P1363 format.
`PlainDsaEncoding.Instance.Decode()` // Decode to signature `BigInteger[]` again. (r, s)

Note: `ECDsaSigner` can wrapped inside `DsaDigestSigner` to allow hash of message automatically. or compute hash(message) manually then use `ECDsaSigner` exactly like [@Topaco other post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68899029/deterministic-signatures-using-bouncycastle-sha-256withplain-ecdsa).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For P1363 it's irrelevant whether the deterministic or non-deterministic ECDSA algorithm is used to determine the signature.

In P1363:

- r and s are contained as unsigned, big endian arrays
- r and s are padded to their maximum size (length of the order of the generator point) with leading 0x00 values

In your code, r (`toto[0]`) and s (`toto[1]`) are both of type `Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger`. The conversion to P1363 is then simply possible with (for simplicity, the maximum size is not calculated, but passed):

```cs
using Org.BouncyCastle.Math;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.Encoders;
using System;

// r and s as BigIntegers
BigInteger r = new BigInteger("184277181267172538606383136781492460232995304963063764346199145255201368533");
BigInteger s = new BigInteger("59980738789003505646930326203273200546254161299399868639304126982806381806190");

// Convert to unsigned, big endian arrays
var rBytes = r.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
var sBytes = s.ToByteArrayUnsigned(); 

// Pad to maximum size 
int maxSize = 32;
byte[] rsBytes = new byte[2 * maxSize];
Buffer.BlockCopy(rBytes, 0, rsBytes, maxSize - rBytes.Length, rBytes.Length);     
Buffer.BlockCopy(sBytes, 0, rsBytes, 2 * maxSize - sBytes.Length, sBytes.Length); 
Console.WriteLine(Hex.ToHexString(rsBytes)); // 00684c148ab8582b55fa0929de7853503a05f57119d80cb8b0172103eca369d5849be52463b4911ab97c4cbb17322afc0be9a973269d9d263e23bdd43f18426e
```

The output is 2 * `maxSize` bytes large and for this example:

```
00684c148ab8582b55fa0929de7853503a05f57119d80cb8b0172103eca369d5849be52463b4911ab97c4cbb17322afc0be9a973269d9d263e23bdd43f18426e
```

The first `maxSize` bytes are r, the last `maxSize` bytes are s.

For comparison: The same signature in ASN.1/DER format is:

```
3044021f684c148ab8582b55fa0929de7853503a05f57119d80cb8b0172103eca369d5022100849be52463b4911ab97c4cbb17322afc0be9a973269d9d263e23bdd43f18426e
```

---

**Edit:**

The OP pointed out that BouncyCastle already has implementations for this conversion. This is indeed the case:

```cs
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Signers;

// Applied curve: secp256r1 aka P-256 aka prime256v1   
BigInteger n = new BigInteger(1, Convert.FromHexString("FFFFFFFF00000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBCE6FAADA7179E84F3B9CAC2FC632551")); // n: order of generator point
                                                        
byte[] p1363 = PlainDsaEncoding.Instance.Encode(n, r, s);
Console.WriteLine(Hex.ToHexString(p1363)); // 00684c148ab8582b55fa0929de7853503a05f57119d80cb8b0172103eca369d5849be52463b4911ab97c4cbb17322afc0be9a973269d9d263e23bdd43f18426e

byte[] asn1Der = StandardDsaEncoding.Instance.Encode(n, r, s);
Console.WriteLine(Hex.ToHexString(asn1Der)); // 3044021f684c148ab8582b55fa0929de7853503a05f57119d80cb8b0172103eca369d5022100849be52463b4911ab97c4cbb17322afc0be9a973269d9d263e23bdd43f18426e
```

The `Encode()` methods determine the maximum size from the order n of the generator point.